# How to redirect user to login page instantly after token expires

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I am trying to redirect user to login page instantly after token expires and not after the next click how it is now. I have set

```
PostLogoutRedirectUri, FrontChannelLogoutUri, IdentityTokenLifetime, AccessTokenLifetime
```

correctly and it works fine redirecting user to login page after expiration of token. But it's not instant and requires a click. Is there a way to redirect user instantly?

Comment: Just curious, why does it matter? What is the difference? You can use a javascript timer (based on the token expiration time) to reset the location (refresh page).

Comment: If people writes a long input for textbox it may take longer than token lifetime. After submitting and being redirected to login all progress is lost

Comment: I’d avoid linking your application session to token lifetime - that’s really not necessary as you can refresh the token without user interaction if you wish.

Comment: But I want user to be logged out after inactivity. What I don't want is user thinking he is logged in and making proggress just to find out after submission that he was not logged out after all.

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis are you using cookie authentication in your app or is it a client side app that uses the bearer token issued by `identityserver4` to talk to the back end?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and can show my solution:

Some explaining words:

Using cookie authentication, the user gets a cookie containing an authentication ticket. The ticket is encrypted by the server and contains a lifetime. Every time a request is sent, the security ticket is sent with it and the lifetime is evaluated by the server. Then, if the remaining lifetime is less than half of the configured session lifetime, the lifetime in the authentication ticket is resetted.

My approach:

Knowing the process, the only solution I came up with, was to handle logout (and in my scenario session renewal) on client side. The general approach is to start a JS counter counting to session time configured by the server; Showing a popup for renewal 3 minutes before the lifetime ends and redirecting to the login page one minute before the session lifetime ends.

Here are some snippets I used:

This is part of all of my templates:

```
jQuery(function{
        @if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["timeOutValue"] != null)
        {
            @:var timeOutMinute = @HttpContext.Current.Session["timeOutValue"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            @:var timeOutMinute = 20;
        }

        localStorage.setItem("timeoutInMinutes", timeOutMinute)
        sessionWarning(timeOutMinute);
});
```

This is my function handling timer and renewal dialogue:

```
function sessionWarning(timeoutMinutes) {
var warningTime = ((timeoutMinutes - 3) * 60 * 1000);
var sessionTimer = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("sessionTimer"));
if ((sessionTimer !== null) && (sessionTimer < ((timeoutMinutes * 60 * 1000) / 2))) {
    warningTime = warningTime - sessionTimer;
}
else {
    localStorage.setItem("sessionTimer", "0");
    sessionTimer = 0;
}
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery("#modal-session-container").modal();
}, warningTime);
intervalTimer = setInterval(function () {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("sessionTimer")))) {
        localStorage.setItem("sessionTimer", "0");
    }
    if (!isNaN(timer)) {
        localStorage.setItem("sessionTimer", String(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("sessionTimer")) + 1000));
    }
}, 1000);
}
```

I hope this helps!